# Elasticsearch Filtering woes, uppercase vs lowercase field filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a field in my index called "status" of keyword type.

When I try to filter with {"term": {"status": "Publish"}}, it returns no hits
When I try to filter with {"term": {"status": 'publish"}}, it returns the correct result.

This would be one thing if the status was input as lowercase, but they're actually uppercase.

My kibana GET returns the products with "status": "Publish".

I also remember inserting the statuses with uppercase values. So why can I only filter by lowercase?

The big caveat, and I know its suspicious to do this, is I attempted to add the "status" mapping after the item indices were already created. Thats the main culprit for me right now as to why this is happening.

Does anyone know why the filtering only works with lowercase values when the actual value in the mapping is uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is the default analyzer if no analyzer is specified. So, `Publish` gets indexed as `publish`.

If you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add .keyword to the status field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after status field).

The [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) does not apply any analyzers to the search term, so will only look for that exact term in the inverted index. So to search for the exact term, you need to use status.keyword OR change the mapping of the field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status.keyword": "Publish"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've just querying my mapping again in Kibana. It doesn't have status as keyword, it has it as type text apprently. Must be some messed up thing where if you have an existing indice and try to add mappings to it, it messes up. I believe that since it is type "text" that it automatically converted it to lowercase.

Comment: @VincentTomie can you please share your index mapping for `status` field?

Comment: "status" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },

Comment: According to this, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html. Whoops lol

Comment: @VincentTomie based on your index mapping, the search query given in the answer will give you correct result

Comment: @VincentTomie can you please try the query given in the answer above, and let me know if this works for you ?

Comment: Yes, it did work. Thank you very much. I'll have to review how I add mappings to the Elasticsearch because I can clearly see that I added it as a keyword. Guess I shouldn't be remapping already created Indices.

Comment: @VincentTomie I think you are using the default index mapping, and you have not explicitly added any index mapping

Comment: I have a python script that defined the mapping for the items. I attempted to add status a keyword to that mapping. I didn't change the mapping directly through Kibana. Based on my process I was supposed to create another items bucket and re-index all the items with the correct mapping instead of trying to force elasticsearch to guess the correct mapping.